# mutate a new column on original df with quantiles?

Tags: r

e.g.

```
diamonds$carat %>% quantile(probs = seq(0.1:1, by = 0.05))
 10%  15%  20%  25%  30%  35%  40%  45%  50%  55%  60%  65%  70%  75%  80%  85%  90%  95% 100% 
0.31 0.32 0.35 0.40 0.42 0.50 0.53 0.60 0.70 0.73 0.90 1.00 1.01 1.04 1.13 1.24 1.51 1.70 5.01
```

Is there a clever 'tidyverse' way or otherwise to mutate a new column onto diamonds with the quantile from above that each observation belongs?

Comment: You cannot have a single column with that output because of the length difference.  I posted a solution below.  May be it helps.

Comment: You're missing the first two tiles: `0-5%` and `5-10%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get empirical quantiles by normalizing the rank according to the length of the vector:

```
percentile <- function(x) round(100 * (rank(x) - 1)/(length(x) - 1), 2)

diamonds %>% mutate(carat_percentile = percentile(carat))
#> # A tibble: 53,940 x 11
#>    carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z carat_percentile
#>    <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>
#>  1 0.23  Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43             0.32
#>  2 0.21  Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31             0.03
#>  3 0.23  Good      E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31             0.32
#>  4 0.290 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63             2.84
#>  5 0.31  Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75             9.88
#>  6 0.24  Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48             0.83
#>  7 0.24  Very Good I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47             0.83
#>  8 0.26  Very Good H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53             1.69
#>  9 0.22  Fair      E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49             0.04
#> 10 0.23  Very Good H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39             0.32
#> # ... with 53,930 more rows
```

We can confirm this is right by converting the percentiles we obtained for the first five members of `carat` back into `quantile`, and seeing that they match:

```
quantile(diamonds$carat, percentile(diamonds$carat)[1:5]/100)
#> 0.32% 0.03% 0.32% 2.84% 9.88% 
#>  0.23  0.21  0.23  0.29  0.31
```

There is also the `percentile_rank` function in dplyr, which is similar, but is not quite the inverse of the `quantile` function in the way that the simple function above is.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cut`.

```
data(diamonds, package="ggplot2")
library(dplyr)

diamonds %>%
  mutate(tile5=cut(carat, breaks=quantile(carat, probs=seq(0,1,0.05)), include=T, labels=F)) %>%
  select(carat, tile5)
# A tibble: 53,940 x 2
   carat tile5
   <dbl> <int>
 1 0.23      1
 2 0.21      1
 3 0.23      1
 4 0.290     1
 5 0.31      2
 6 0.24      1
 7 0.24      1
 8 0.26      1
 9 0.22      1
10 0.23      1
# ... with 53,930 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

As there are multiple observations, we can create a `list` column and then use `unnest_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
diamonds %>%
   mutate(new = list(as.list(quantile(carat, probs = seq(0.1:1, by = 0.05))))) %>%
    unnest_wider(c(new))
# A tibble: 53,940 x 29
#   carat cut   color clarity depth table price     x     y     z `10%` `15%` `20%` `25%` `30%` `35%` `40%` `45%` `50%` `55%` `60%` `65%`
#   <dbl> <ord> <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 0.23  Ideal E     SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43  0.31  0.32  0.35   0.4  0.42   0.5  0.53   0.6   0.7  0.73   0.9     1
# 2 0.21  Prem… E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31  0.31  0.32  0.35   0.4  0.42   0.5  0.53   0.6   0.7  0.73   0.9     1
# 3 0.23  Good  E     VS1      56.9    65   327  4.05  4.07  2.31  0.31  0.32  0.35   0.4  0.42   0.5  0.53   0.6   0.7  0.73   0.9     1
# 4 0.290 Prem… I     VS2      62.4    58   334  4.2   4.23  2.63  0.31  0.32  0.35   0.4  0.42   0.5  0.53   0.6   0.7  0.73   0.9     1
# 5 0.31  Good  J     SI2      63.3    58   335  4.34  4.35  2.75  0.31  0.32  0.35   0.4  0.42   0.5  0.53   0.6   0.7  0.73   0.9     1
# 6 0.24  Very… J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48  0.31  0.32  0.35   0.4  0.42   0.5  0.53   0.6   0.7  0.73   0.9     1
# 7 0.24  Very… I     VVS1     62.3    57   336  3.95  3.98  2.47  0.31  0.32  0.35   0.4  0.42   0.5  0.53   0.6   0.7  0.73   0.9     1
# 8 0.26  Very… H     SI1      61.9    55   337  4.07  4.11  2.53  0.31  0.32  0.35   0.4  0.42   0.5  0.53   0.6   0.7  0.73   0.9     1
# 9 0.22  Fair  E     VS2      65.1    61   337  3.87  3.78  2.49  0.31  0.32  0.35   0.4  0.42   0.5  0.53   0.6   0.7  0.73   0.9     1
#10 0.23  Very… H     VS1      59.4    61   338  4     4.05  2.39  0.31  0.32  0.35   0.4  0.42   0.5  0.53   0.6   0.7  0.73   0.9     1
# … with 53,930 more rows, and 7 more variables: `70%` <dbl>, `75%` <dbl>, `80%` <dbl>, `85%` <dbl>, `90%` <dbl>, `95%` <dbl>,
#   `100%` <dbl>
```

Comment: Ah, that adds a new column for each value. What I meant is a single new column that contains the quantile for each row.